# Losing a connection during query execution

Tags: mysql

Suppose this situation:

I have an insert query which has an auto-increment key

```
Insert into xxx Values(0, 1)
```

What will happen if I call `mysql_query(&sql, szQuery)` but the connection to the server is lost, since physical network error.

I have this question since my project has a wrapper with SQL, and want to do auto retry if query is failed since net error, it will happen in actual environment every day which called net flash disconnect and reconnect.

Sometimes, the client will not get the query result, but the server has finished the insert query. How can I sync the state between client and server in this case?

There is no other unique data except primary key, it's about a common query operation, so in my project, we would like to retry insert queries, if an insert query has pre-defined key (such as GUID), retry will ok, but if the Primary key is auto increment, the retry operation may be has two rows.

In my project, we use auto commit, so if a row data has inserted, and the ack of the query is not sent to client since net error, is there a better way to check whether need insert again for auto-increment rows?

Answer (score 0):

> What will happen if I call `mysql_query(&sql, szQuery)` but the connection to the server is lost, since physical network error.

If you are in an explicit transaction (after `BEGIN` or `START` TRANSACTION, but before `COMMIT`), then the statements will be rollbacked due to non-committed transaction.

Outside an explicit transaction, think of `AUTOCOMMIT` as an implicit transaction containing a single query.

In either case, testing for errors after the query will let you know whether the query finished.

> How can I sync the state between client and server in this case?

Maybe this needs in sync from the client side, but from the server side this will be new and independent connection from new client - so sync like the client has just been launched. And you must understand that the query may be not committed yet, so you'll not see the changes made by the query immediately. You may need to refresh your data again after a while.

> ...is there a better way to check whether need insert again for auto-increment rows?

Identify the connection which sends the query. Wait until the query is executed completely (processlist shows that this connection is in wait or close state) then check if the data which should be inserted is present in a table.

Do not "auto-reconnect" (an option in some APIs).  If, for example, you are part-way through an *explicit* connection when auto-reconnect kicks in, you will have a mess.  The first part will be rolled back, then a new transaction is started.

Because of the what `AUTO_INCREMENT` is handled, a rolled back `INSERT` may have already consumed a number.  Do *not* ever depend on such ids not having gaps.